# C++: My program only read the numbers I input as hundreds though I typed it as thousands

Tags: c++

Here's the given of my assignment:

> Compute for the cash value of a P 25,000 Savings Bond at any time according to the following:
>
> - If the Bond is less than 6 months old, the interest is zero percent.
> - If the Bond is between 6 and 12 months old, the interest rate is 1 percent.
> - If the Bond is between 13 to 18 months old, the interest rate is 2 percent.
> - If the bond is between 19 to 24 months old, the interest rate is 3.5 percent.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Savings_Bond = 25000;
    int Age_Bond = 6 && 12 && 13 && 18 && 19 && 24;
    int Interest = 0.01 && 0.02 && 0.035;
    int TotalV;

    cout << "How long this bond been on? : ";
    cin >> Age_Bond;

    if (Age_Bond < 6)
    {
        TotalV = Savings_Bond * 0;
        cout << "Your Interest Rate : "
             << "0%"
             << "\n";
        cout << "Total Value : " << TotalV << "\n";
    }
    else if (Age_Bond = 6 + 12)
    {
        TotalV = Savings_Bond * 0.01;
        cout << "Your Interest Rate : "
             << "1%"
             << "\n";
        cout << "Total Value : " << TotalV << "\n";
    }
    else if (Age_Bond = 13 + 18)
    {
        TotalV = Savings_Bond * 0.02;
        cout << "Your Interest Rate : "
             << "2%"
             << "\n";
        cout << "Total Value : " << TotalV << "\n";
    }
    else if (Age_Bond = 19 + 24)
    {
        TotalV = Savings_Bond * 0.035;
        cout << "Your Interest Rate : "
             << "3.5%"
             << "\n";
        cout << "Total Value : " << TotalV << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here's how it looks:

```
How long this bond been on? : 17
Your Interest Rate : 1%
Total Value : 250
```

Comment: `int Age_Bond = 6 && 12 && 13 && 18 && 19 && 24;` will initialize `Age_Bond` to `1`. Add print outs of your variables to debug your program - or run it in an actual debugger. Also, in `if (Age_Bond = 6 + 12)` you are assigning `18` to `Age_Bond`.

Comment: Can you explain what this line does? `int Interest = 0.01 && 0.02 && 0.035;`

Comment: Also note that `Age_Bond = 6 + 12` will perform an assignment, not a comparison (that is `==`)

Comment: This has the look of code that used to be nearly right, but has got worse and worse as a result of fruitless efforts to fix the original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have some misunderstandings about how conditional expressions work in C++.

> If the Bond is between 6 and 12 months old, the interest rate is 1
> percent

In C++ that is written like this

```
else if (Age_Bond >= 6 && Age_Bond <= 12)
```

You have some other issues

```
int Age_Bond = 6 && 12 && 13 && 18 && 19 && 24;
int Interest = 0.01 && 0.02 && 0.035;
```

I'm not sure what you think those declarations are doing, but it's nothing useful. You don't use the `Interest` variable, so you can just delete that. And the `Age_Bond` variable gets it's value from the user input so you don't need to give is a value here. Just use

```
int Age_Bond;
```

Finally your value calculations are incorrect. If the interest is 0% then the value of the bond is 25000, but according to your calculations the value will be zero. If the interest is 1% then the value is 25250, but your calculation gives 250, etc. Basically you need to add the interest to the existing value.

Comment: Thank you so much, and yeah my calculations are totally wrong thank you for the reminder i`m fixing it now.